# How i can improve the code?

Tags: for-loop, go, slice

I'm beginner in programming. Could i use two elements in golang for-loops? If you know answer, or material which i should read, please help me.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := []int{
        48, 96, 86, 68,
        57, 82, 63, 70,
        37, 34, 83, 27,
        19, 97, 9, 17,
    }

    for a := 0, b := 1; a++, b++ {
        if x[a] > x[b] {
            x = append(x[:1], x[1+1:]...)
            fmt.Println("x[1+1:]x)", x)
        } else {
            x = append(x[:0], x[0+1:]...)
            fmt.Println("x[0+1:]x)", x)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Golang for loops: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for

Comment: Yes you can. Your syntax is wrong see https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, although it's unnecessary in this case.

The `syntax` function fixes the syntax and other errors in your code so that your code runs and produces output. The `idiom` function rewrites your code in a more idiomatic form.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func syntax() {
    x := []int{
        48, 96, 86, 68,
        57, 82, 63, 70,
        37, 34, 83, 27,
        19, 97, 9, 17,
    }

    for a, b := 0, 1; a < len(x) && b < len(x); a, b = a+1, b+1 {
        if x[a] > x[b] {
            x = append(x[:1], x[1+1:]...)
            fmt.Println("x[1+1:]x)", x)
        } else {
            x = append(x[:0], x[0+1:]...)
            fmt.Println("x[0+1:]x)", x)
        }
    }
}

func idiom() {
    x := []int{
        48, 96, 86, 68,
        57, 82, 63, 70,
        37, 34, 83, 27,
        19, 97, 9, 17,
    }

    for i := 1; i < len(x); i++ {
        if x[i-1] > x[i] {
            x = append(x[:1], x[1+1:]...)
            fmt.Println("x[1+1:]x)", x)
        } else {
            x = append(x[:0], x[0+1:]...)
            fmt.Println("x[0+1:]x)", x)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    syntax()
    fmt.Println()
    idiom()
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run beginner.go
x[0+1:]x) [96 86 68 57 82 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[1+1:]x) [96 68 57 82 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[0+1:]x) [68 57 82 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[0+1:]x) [57 82 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[1+1:]x) [57 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[1+1:]x) [57 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[0+1:]x) [70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[0+1:]x) [37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]

x[0+1:]x) [96 86 68 57 82 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[1+1:]x) [96 68 57 82 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[0+1:]x) [68 57 82 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[0+1:]x) [57 82 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[1+1:]x) [57 63 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[1+1:]x) [57 70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[0+1:]x) [70 37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
x[0+1:]x) [37 34 83 27 19 97 9 17]
```

Follow the link to take [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/).